# Can you set up a transfer from an S3 bucket subfolder to a GCS bucket with only the credentials to access the S3 subfolder, not the root folder?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, subdirectory, data-transfer

I'm looking to set up a transfer job to take files stored within an S3 bucket and load them to a GCS bucket. The credentials that I have give me access to the folder that contains the files that I need from S3 but not to the higher level folders.

When I try to set up the transfer job with the S3 bucket name under 'Amazon S3 bucket' and the access key ID & secret access key filled-in, the access is denied as you would expect given the limits of my credentials. However, access is *still* denied if I add the extra path information as a Prefix item (e.g. 'Production/FTP/CompanyName') and I do have access to this folder.

It seems as though I can't get past the fact that I do not have access to the root directory. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Pradeep. Yes, the message is 'Failed to obtain the location of the source S3 bucket. Additional details: Access Denied'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/iam-transfer#source-permissions):

> The Storage Transfer Service uses the
>   project-[$PROJECT_NUMBER]@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>   service account to move data from a Cloud Storage source bucket.
>
> The service account must have the following permissions for the source
>   bucket:
>
> storage.buckets.get   Allows the service account to get the location of
>   the bucket.   Always required.
>
> storage.objects.list  Allows the service account to list objects in the
>   bucket.   Always required.
>
> storage.objects.get   Allows the service account to read objects in the
>   bucket.   Always required.
>
> storage.objects.delete    Allows the service account to delete objects in
>   the bucket.   Required if you set deleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer
>   to true.
>
> The roles/storage.objectViewer and roles/storage.legacyBucketReader
>   roles together contain the permissions that are always required. The
>   roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter role contains the
>   storage.objects.delete permissions. The service account used to
>   perform the transfer must be assigned the desired roles.

You have to set this permissions on your AWS bucket.

Comment: Thank you but this sucks. Why should I even give this permission on root level? When other tools (e.g. cyberduck) can work without this permission then why they cannot?

Comment: @BehrozSikander This is only because Google (for whatever reasons) doesn't care to implement access to deeper s3 directories in their web console interface to transfers. You can do this manually using a VM instance as an intermediary; I'll write this up as an answer if you like, as I just had to do it!

Comment: @jkf how would you go about doing just that?

Answer (score -1):

Paul,

Most likely your IAM role is missing `s3:ListBucket` permission. Can you update your IAM role to have `s3:ListBucket` , `s3:GetBucketLocation`  and try again?

Answer (score -2):

On AWS permission policy should like below , in case you want to give access to subfolder.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",

    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "<subfolder>/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/<subfolder>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/<subfolder>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```