# s3/gcs - Copy s3 subdirectory to gcs without access to root?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, data-transfer

I'm trying to use the GCP Data Transfer service to move files from an s3 bucket (that I don't own) to a GCS bucket (that I do own).

I only have access to a sub-directory/specific path within that s3 bucket. I have also confirmed the credentials are correct using an independent s3 client. With this client, I can view and download files within that path.

Each time I try to set up a transfer job with this path I get this error - "Failed to obtain the location of the source s3 bucket. Additional details: access denied"

My only guess is data transfer requires access to the whole bucket to copy a sub directory.

Can anyone provide any more insight? Or confirm my hunch?

Comment: You are right, you need to give permissions to the whole bucket. Similar as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818676/can-you-set-up-a-transfer-from-an-s3-bucket-subfolder-to-a-gcs-bucket-with-only). That's a bummer, I know.

Comment: Thank you for confirming...I did see that question but honestly wasn't sure if the answer was an unequivocal 'yes.' Wanted to get absolute confirmation before I went back to the team with confidence :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)